# Is the factory pattern what I need?

Tags: design-patterns, optimization

I'm just wanting some clarity on my thinking before I start building something. I'm building an importer and the importer will always accept the following data:

**[SKU, Name, Color]**

However, the data sent to the importer could use different column names and in different file formats (CSV or excel plus others) because of the vendor. So do I need to create some sort of mapper to say X column means X column in my DB?

I'm thinking the best way to do this is to build an interface which then each vendor has its own implementation of it that contains a column name mapper then uses a factory pattern to build the final object.

I could be totally wrong, so has anyone had experience with building such things and what did you use?

Thanks
Oli

Comment: plus 243 others means that you want to hardcode 243 properties !?!?!?!

Comment: Hey, to make it easier I just removed that part. I was basically trying to say I had 243 other properties which would be mapped

Comment: So, you need two mappings: columns and file formats?

Comment: I need an original column name and a imported column name and it maps the imported data to the correct column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory can be good solution for your situation, but IMHO it will not take into account changes in two places: source and columns. If you have just one potential place for changes, then factory is great. But if you have two places ( data source and columns ) consider maybe abstract factory. Another solution which I can propose for your case is to use bridge with ISourceImporter ( for Excel, csv, other sources ) with IMapper ( for different combinations of columns ). It will give you possibility to easily add new source importers and easily add new combinations of columns. IMHO Bridge will be better solution.